# c what order is this while loop done?

Tags: c

```
char destination[6];
char source[] = "hello";
char* a = destination;
char* b = source;

while (*a++ = *b++);
return destination;
```

Does it set *a to *b and then check if value != 0 and then increment the pointers?

Or does it do something like increment the pointers and then check *a = *b value of what it was before and then check != 0?

Comment: You can infer this by running the code. You may want to use a debugger for a step by step view.

Comment: What have you done to understand the **post**increment operator? The increments are unsequenced with respect to the expression.

Comment: @RadLexus: Learning C or any other weakly typed language by trial and error is a bad idea. It becomes worse with side-effect operators.

Comment: well I do run the code but it isnt obvious what order the while loop condition is done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A while loop like:

```
while (<expr>) <body>;
```

is executed as if it were:

```
while (true) {
    int temp = <expr>;
    if (!temp) {
        break;
    }
    <body>
}
```

So it evaluates the entire `<expr>`, including any side effects (such as assignments and increments), before testing whether the value is zero.

The expression `temp = *a++ = *b++` is evaluated as:

```
int new_a = a + 1; int new_b = b + 1; // These may be evaluated in either order
temp = (*a = *b); // value of temp will be that value that was assigned to *a
a = new_a; b = new_b; // Also in either order
```

So the value that's tested is whatever was assigned before the variables were incremented.

Comment: That doesn't quite answer the question. `<expr>` is `*a++ = *b++`, and I think the OP wants to know what will be assigned to `temp`.

Comment: @Caleb Thanks, I've added some more "as if" that shows how that gets evaluated.

Comment: @Barmar So it increments the pointers first despite being post increment, but assigns the deference of the a-- to  the dereference of b-- and then checks if that assignment was != 0?

Comment: It doesn't increment the pointers first. That's why the addition is assigned to `new_a` and `new_b` -- they hold the incremented value while the assignment is done.

Comment: Ok thanks, would the expression be much different in order if it was pre-increment?

Comment: Yes, then it would start with `a = a + 1; b = b + 1;` and then do `*a = *b;`. So the loop would skip the first element of the array.

Comment: Maybe you should go back to your textbook/tutorial and re-read the explanation of pre-increment and post-increment.

Answer (score 3):

First, *b is evaluated and the value is assigned to *a.
Second, the side effects of ++ happen (a++ and b++).
Third, the value of *a before the post increment is used to decide whether to enter or to exit the loop.

In other words, you could translate the program into the following equivalent representation:

```
int main(){
  char  destination[6];
  char  source[] = "hello";
  char* a = destination;
  char* b = source;

  while (1){
    *a=*b;
    int tmp=*a;
    a = a + 1;
    b = b + 1;
    if (!(tmp))
      break;
    // the original loop body comes here
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **postincrement** operator first uses its operand in the context of its expression, then increments its value.

So in this case, you are correct.  It sets `*a` to `*b` then increments `a` and `b`, since the postincrement `++` operator has higher precedence than the dereference operator `*`.  And since the assignment is evaluated last, the value assigned is the value of the expression, which `while` then checks for true/false, i.e. non-zero or zero.

The actual increment happens at some point after its operand is evaluated.  For this reason, using the `++` or `--` operators on the same variable in the same expression without a sequence point leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: But what is the value of the expression `*a++ = *b++`?

Answer (score -1):

> Does it set *a to *b and then check if value != 0 and then increment the pointers?

It increments the pointers, deferences them, assigns the value and the expression yields that value ie after it assigns the NULL it will be evaluated as false and stop.

Order of precedence

1. ++
2. *
3. =

Answer (score -1):

The assignment operator evaluates from [**right-to-left**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) and has a lower precedence (order of evaluation) than the `++` (post-increment) operator.

To answer your question,

```
while (*a++ = *b++);
```

First `*b++` is evaluated, then `*a++` is evaluated. Since this is post increment, the previous value of `*a` gets the previous value of `*b`. Finally the expression is converted to a boolean and if `b` was not pointing to null address, the expression evaluates to true, otherwise false.

It is equivalent to this:

```
while (*a = *b) {
    ++a, ++b;
}
```